# How to output data from Yaml variables (written in markdown) into an HTML Haml file?

Tags: yaml, markdown, haml, middleman

In a Yaml data file `aaa.yml` I have:

```
yyy: |
     [foo](http://example.com) bar.
```

I want to pull this data from a Haml file (`zzz.html.haml`).

**1**. If I do `zzz.html.haml`:

```
    %p
      = data.aaa.yyy
```

- Middleman renders `zzz.html`:

  `<p> [foo](http://example.com) bar</p>`

**2**. If I do:

```
    %p
      :markdown
        = data.aaa.yyy
```

- Middleman renders:

  `<p>= data.aaa.yyy</p>`

**How can I make it render:**

`<p><a href="http://example.com">foo</a> bar</p>`

?

Answer (score 1):

You have a string that contains markdown, and you want to render that markdown and include the result in your output.

One way would be to use the Haml `:markdown` filter. You can’t use normal Haml syntax inside a filter (like you’ve tried), but you can use interpolation inside `#{...}`, so you could do

```haml
:markdown
  #{data.aaa.yyy}
```

A better way, if the string is a standalone chunk, might be to create a helper method that renders markdown, and call that.

Wherever you have your helpers add something like:

```ruby
def markdown s
  # I'm using kramdown here, but you can use whatever processor you prefer.
  Kramdown::Document.new(s).to_html
end
```

Then in your Haml:

```haml
= markdown(data.aaa.yyy)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yay! Turns out there's [this helper](https://forum.middlemanapp.com/t/rendering-markdown-from-json-data-file/1845/2), which was already in my config.rb but didn't work by itself:

```
def markdown(text)
  Tilt['markdown'].new { text }.render
end
```

When I installed this helper (from [@matt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44014190/5455207)) with the first one:

```
def markdown s
  Kramdown::Document.new(s).to_html
end
```

Then `= markdown(foo.bar)` worked, which made my day!! :D

Comment: This second helper doesn't reference first in any way. I don't know why the first didn't work (it does for me), but the reason why adding second one works is that it overwrites definition of `markdown` and the first one isn't used at all. You can remove first helper and nothing will change.

Comment: And if anyone wants to use the first helper, you need to add app context in order for it to work fully in all cases. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44494649/1226389).