# Middleman: undefined method `link_to' when rendering markdown from data file

Tags: markdown, middleman, kramdown, tilt

I am using Markdown written in data file to render HTML in HAML template with Middleman static page generator.

My data file, `data/faq.yaml` looks like this:

```
dog:
  question: I want to know more about a dog.
  answerA: (HTML in data) Just <a href="https://google.com">Google</a> it!
  answerB: (Markdown link in data) Just [Google](https://google.com) it!
```

To convert this markdown to HTML, I am using custom helper defined in `config.rb`:

```
helpers do
    def markdown(text)
        Tilt['markdown'].new { text }.render
    end
end
```

Which then I use in my HAML template like this:

```
= markdown(data.faq.dog.answerA)
```

Everything works perfectly until I try to render markdown link written in data file.

Below is my `faq.haml` template with:

- Markdown link written directly in HAML, which renders through HAML's markdown filter
- Reference to `answerA` from data with HTML link written directly
- Reference to `answerB` from data with same link written with markdown syntax

`faq.haml`:

```
.answer
    :markdown
        (HAML) Just [Google](https://google.com) it!
    = markdown(data.faq.dog.answerA)
    = markdown(data.faq.dog.answerB)
```

First 2 links render propely, but markdown link in `answerB` throws following error:

```
undefined method `link_to' for #<Object:0x000000044f9e18>
```

Traceback:

```
/home/myself/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/middleman-core-4.2.1/lib/middleman-core/renderers/kramdown.rb: in convert_a
    48.     scope.link_to(content, link, attr)
```

Why is Kramdown unable to convert a markdown link when "asked" to do so via custom helper which references data file, but does it properly when same syntax is used directly in HAML? What can be done, so that markdown link in `= markdown(data.faq.dog.answerB)` renders properly?

Ps. My end goal will be to reference links which are already defined in separate `data` file, but I think that solving this issue first is necessary in order to achieve that goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App context needs to passed to Tilt.

```
def markdown(text)
  Tilt['markdown'].new(context: @app) { text }.render
end
```

[Source](https://forum.middlemanapp.com/t/rendering-markdown-from-json-data-file/1845/4?u=rafael)